# Angular 6.x Map operator not exist for Observable<Data> with ActivatedRoute

Tags: angular, angular-router

I had a problem recently, and found no tips on how to get it work. When I use ActivatedRoute in order to get data from my Routes, angular failed to compile and say `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Data>'.`

I tried everything like :

```
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import 'rxjs/operators';
```

or even

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

but the error persists.

Here is the route path that I have :

```
{
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, data: { title: "Accueil" }
},
{
    path:'projets', component: ProjectsComponent, data: { title: "Projets"}
}
```

and the component code:

```
constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.map( data => data.title).subscribe(title => console.log(title));
}
```

Do you have any idea what is required now ? It worked before upgrading to Angular 6.

Thanks in advance for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular 6.x uses `rxjs 6.x`. In rxjs6.x, you need to chain other **[pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#pipeable-operators)** in `Observable`'s `pipe` operator.

```
this.route.data
          .pipe(
             map( data => data.title)
            )
          .subscribe(title => console.log(title));
```