# 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<Response>' Nativescript

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, nativescript

I need to get all my alarms form web service in Nativescript. But .map doesn't function. I tried this function. In Angular 5 works good, but in Nativescript show this error:

[ts] Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable'. in this  .map((response: Response) => {

I import this: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';`
 but nothing happens

My   "rxjs": "~6.1.0",

```
 public AlarmsGetAll(): Observable<Alarm[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOnsiVXNlcklEIjoiMzEwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAifSwiaWF0IjoxNTI4ODgzNDU1LCJleHAiOjE1Mjk3NDc0NTV9.qei48rzt1KF9AKIEz8Aq-A8pWkESc1G3jBUfdU27oYE');
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.AlarmsGetAll), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
         console.log(res)
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(alarm => {
            //console.log(alarm)
            return new Alarm(alarm);
          });
        }
      });
  }
```

Can you ask me any idea, what is the problem?

Comment: All you need to know is here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6.x Map operator not exist for Observable<Data> with ActivatedRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50340749/angular-6-x-map-operator-not-exist-for-observabledata-with-activatedroute)

Comment: @martin I wonder what `import` mechanism will be in v7 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use rxjs@6, you should update operator.

**Rxjs 5**

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

myObservable
  .map(yourdata=> yourdata + 15)
  .subscribe(...);
```

**Rxjs 6**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

myObservable
  .pipe(map(yourdata=> yourdata + 15))
  .subscribe(...);
```

**Solution in your case :**

So you need to update your import and use the new way of **Rxjs6**

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

 public AlarmsGetAll(): Observable<Alarm[]> {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('x-access-token', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOnsiVXNlcklEIjoiMzEwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAifSwiaWF0IjoxNTI4ODgzNDU1LCJleHAiOjE1Mjk3NDc0NTV9.qei48rzt1KF9AKIEz8Aq-A8pWkESc1G3jBUfdU27oYE');
    return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.AlarmsGetAll), {
      headers: headers
    })
      .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
         console.log(res)
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(alarm => {
            //console.log(alarm)
            return new Alarm(alarm);
          });
        }
      }));
  }
```

[If you need more information](https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/)

Comment: OP is on Angular 6 and using deprecated `HttpModule` instead he should go for `HttpClientModule`

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code modified with the latest version of rxjs v6 and HttpClientModule (HttpModule is deprecated since v5):

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

public AlarmsGetAll(): Observable<Alarm[]> {
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('x-access-token', 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyaWQiOnsiVXNlcklEIjoiMzEwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAifSwiaWF0IjoxNTI4ODgzNDU1LCJleHAiOjE1Mjk3NDc0NTV9.qei48rzt1KF9AKIEz8Aq-A8pWkESc1G3jBUfdU27oYE');
return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.AlarmsGetAll), {
  headers: headers,
  observe: 'response'
}).pipe(
  map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
    let res = response.json();
     console.log(res)
    if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
    } else {
      return res.StatusDescription.map(alarm => {
        //console.log(alarm)
        return new Alarm(alarm);
      });
    }
  }));
}
```

As mentionned previously you can check the migration guideline to update rxjs v5 to v6 and here is the documentation for HttpClientModule :
[Angular http documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Comment: HttpResponse<any>

Answer (score 0):

The latest NativeScript uses Angular 6 and Rxjs 6.1.0 and above. Check the migration guidelines for moving from rxjs@5 to rxjs@6

---